# Regex change to "" not working

Tags: c#, regex

I need to change:

```
","
":"
"{"
"}"
```

From string to `""`

I wrote this:

```
Regex remove = new Regex("\"\"\":\"\"{\"\"}\"]");
remove.Replace(str, "");
```

But this didn't change the values I needed to change. Where did I make a error?

Comment: I don't see any `,` in your Regex. And why have you used so many `\"`?

Comment: are you trying to replace the comma, period and curly brackets individually or are you trying to replace the entire string """:""{""}"] ?

And did you notice the right angle bracket at the end?

Comment: Perhaps the regex you should be using is `",|:|\\{|\\}"` (comma OR colon OR open brace OR closing brace)

Comment: @Kiyura.. `[,:{}]` looks better.

Answer (score 4):

The replace method returns the replaced string.

You should try

```
Regex remove = new Regex(",|:|\\{|\\}");
str = remove.Replace(str, "");
```

Note: The regex looks for , : { and } within "".

EDIT: Modified Code with regular expressing string as well, thanks to ArsenMkrt

Comment: @ArsenMkrt  No, I dont think it is. As mentioned by the other posters in comments on the question, there are quite a few issues with it.

Comment: I think it would be better, if you fix pattern too.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt There you go. I am not too comfortable with regex myself, so it took me sometime to put it up there. I like to think I am a bit better using .net libraries and components. Thanks for making me include it.

Comment: ",|:|\\{|\\}" here is pattarn